# Let n be a perfect square. Use direct proof to show that n-1 is composite.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

This is the following practice problem from the textbook, *Mathematics, A Discrete Introduction* by Scheinerman.

$1.1$ Let $n$ be a perfect square. Use direct proof to show that if $n \ge 9 $ then $ n -1 $ is composite.

This is the direct proof that I have so far: 
$$ My \; Solution $$
Suppose $n$ is a perfect square. Then there exists some integer $a$ such that $a*a = n$. Suppose then that $n-1$ is composite when $n \ge 9 $. Then there is an integer $b$ such that  $ 1 < b < n-1 $ and $ b|n-1 $. Then $1<b<a^2-1$ and so $b|a^2-1$. If b divides $a^2-1$, which can be factored down to $(a-1)(a+1)$. So $b|(a-1)(a+1)$ and such there are already at least two factors of $n-1$:$ 1, a-1,a+1, a^2-1$ (aka $n-1$). Thus $n-1$ is composite.

$$qed$$
Can someone help me figure out if this proof makes sense, and if not, where I went wrong. Or, if it is correct, anyway I can simplify it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the right idea (which is to factor $a^2-1$), but your argument is incorrect because it assumes what you're trying to prove.

Instead, if $n=a^2$ is a perfect square, then as you noted $n-1=a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$. Now you just have to argue that both $a-1$ and $a+1$ are greater than $1$, which follows from the assumption that $n\geq 9$, so $a\geq 3$.

Comment: This line of thinking makes more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a geometrical proof.

Consider a $n$ by $n$ square
composed of $n^2$
unit squares.

Remove the top right
unit square.

The rightmost column
has $n-1$ squares,
and all the other columns
have $n$ squares.
These other columns form a
$n$ high by $n-1$ wide
rectangle.

Remove the rightmost column,
rotate it by 90 degrees,
and place it at the bottom
of the
$n-1$ wide rectangle.

The rectangle is now
$n+1$ high by $n-1$ wide.

Therefore
$(n+1)(n-1)
= n^2-1$.